# How to create two or more Resolve Field in Resolve Decorator in Nestjs?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, nestjs-graphql

I am creating one `nestjs` `graphql api`. I write all function correctly. But when I need to add  `@ResolveField` into `@Resolver` Decorator, I get into one problem. Can any tell me when I need two `@ResolveField` in one `@Resolver`, then How can I add it?

Here is Category Entity-(`category.entity.ts`)

```
@ObjectType()
export class Category {
    @Field(() => ID, { nullable: false })
    id: ObjectId;
    @Field(() => String, { nullable: false })
    name: string;
    @Field(() => String, { nullable: true })
    description: string;
    @Field(() => [Subcategory], { nullable: true })
    subCategory: Subcategory[];
    @Field(() => Date, { nullable: false })
    createdAt: DateScalar;
    @Field(() => Date, { nullable: false })
    updatedAt: DateScalar;
}
```

And Here is Subcategory Entity (`sub-category.entity.ts`)-

```
@ObjectType()
export class Subcategory {
    @Field(() => ID, { nullable: false })
    id: ObjectId;
    @Field(() => String, { nullable: false })
    name: string;
    @Field(() => Category, { nullable: false })
    category: Category;
    @Field(() => Date, { nullable: false })
    createdAt: DateScalar;
    @Field(() => Date, { nullable: false })
    updatedAt: DateScalar;
}
```

And This is Resolver (`category.resolver.ts`)-

```
@Resolver()
export class CategoryResolver {
    //Constructor
    constructor(private readonly categoryService: CategoryService) { }
    
    //Get All Category
    @Query(() => [Category], { name: "getCategories" })
    categories() {
        return this.categoryService.categories()
    }

    @ResolveField("subCategory", () => [Subcategory])
    subCategoryBatch(
        @Parent() category: Category
    ) {
        console.log(category)
    }



    //Get All Sub Category
    @Query(() => [Subcategory], { name: "getSubCategories" })
    subCategories() {
        return this.categoryService.subCategories();
    }
    @ResolveField("category", () => Category)
    categoryBatch(
        @Parent() subCategory: Subcategory
    ) {
        console.log(subCategory)
    }
}
```

Here you can see two `@ResolveField` Decorator. For working This I need to add Entity in `@Resolver` decorator, like-

`@Resolver(Category)`

or

`@Resolver(Subcategory)`

When I give `Category` then One `ResolveField` work perfectly, other is not working.
Again When I give `Subcategory` then the other is working perfectly, but first one is not working. But When I give together then it gives me error-

`@Resolver(Category, Subcategory)`

Please help me. I need it Please help me. I can't solve it for 3 days. I search for the same things over internet but not finding any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

First i highly recomand you to organize your resolver like :

```
// ====== Queries =======

// ====== Mutations =======

// ====== Resolvers =======
```

Because resolveing field is available for all queries, when your api will grow you 'll need more readable file.

In the model, your Category field or subCat are currently not Category type, it's probably a ID ref to resolve. After resolving, your field become a Category. True question is, in your db, what's the type of your field ?

So try something like this :

```
  // ex for subCategory.entity.ts
  @Prop({ type: String, ref: 'Category' }) // Mongo
  @Field(() => Category) // GraphQL 
  parent: string; // TS
```

Then, to resolve this ref, you have to init a @ResolveField and use the correct service to resolve it, like :

```
  @ResolveField('parent', () => Category) // resolve 'parent' field to return Category type.
  async resolveParentCategory(@Parent() sub: SubCategory) // take parent object, here subCatefory, where the field to resolve exist. 
  {
      // resolve string ID ref, with correct db service to return parent Category.
      return this.service.getOneCat(sub.parent); 
  }
```

In this case, ResolveField resolve 'parent' to return Category type. The function take the @Parent object where the field "parent" to resolve is accessible,an id is expected here. A db service getOneCat resolve this id to return the complete Category object. It will work for all field 'parent' in this resolver now.

I hope i helped you, let me know if you need more explanation.

***Edit - To resolve `subCategory` in `Category` result:***

My example above should resolve your subfield `category` in `SubCategory`, just replace `parent` by `category`.

To resolve `subCategories` in `Category` it's the same way. But, you should have a `subCategory: string[];` for TS in your `Category` model entity.

Then, in your resolver, resolve `subCategory` field, to return `() => [SubCategory]`.
Parent become `@Parent() cat: Category` and resolve it with a service wich can take `ids : string[]` in arg and return all documents asked from your db. Like `return this.service.getSubCatByIds(cat.subCategory)`.

Comment: I have one more Resolver field for subcategory? How can I implement that also?

Comment: check edit above :)

Comment: It is not solve my problem. Can you read my questions again. I actually want to working Two or More `@ResolveField` into one `@Resolver`. By default only one is working. But I need more than one. Please read my questions again. If this is the correct answer, then please clear by giving example.

Comment: Sorry, I mistake something in my questions. I edited my questions. Please see it again.

Comment: ok, i saw, i was not sure, but if your sub-cat is an other data type in your db and in your schema, you have to make an other and separate resolver, specifi to sub cat. I hesitated to said it before, but it's much more efficient and readable to make another resolver specific for subcategories. Then, add this new resolver in the provider field of the module.